# Disable windows automatically connecting to a known public wifi

Tags: windows-10, wireless-networking

Whenever my notebook is in reach of a public WIFI that I was logged-in once, windows connects to the network and opens the browser, showing me the login page. Then I close the the browser and disconnect the wifi. 5 min later the browser reopens, and the notebook is connected again. And Yes, `Connect automatically when in range` is turned off.

Turning off WIFI or forgetting the network every time I get in range of this wifi seems annoying.
Is there a better solution?

Comment: The following article will show you different ways on how to turn off connecting automatically to a wireless in windows 10:https://www.tenforums.com/tutorials/65916-turn-off-connect-automatically-wireless-network-windows-10-a.html

Answer (score 0):

**One:** Clear the forms and auto-logon sections on all browsers that you have used.  Do this so the login will prompt you and you can say No.

Depending on the browser, also look in Control Panel, Credential Manager, Web passwords, and you may be able to remove the password for the public wifi there.

**Two**: Open cmd.exe with Run as Administrator and do the following:

netsh wlan show profiles  (To see all profiles)

netsh wlan delete profile name="Profile Name"  (To delete profile)

Do the latter for each Public Profile name.

The two things together will prevent automatic login.

Also when you are actually in a location, you can "forget" the location wireless with the Wireless Icon for connections.

**Note:**

(1) Even after doing all the above (clear browser auto login forms; clear all wireless profiles), Windows will still ask to connect.  Just say no.

(2) If you do not want it even asking, you need to turn off your wireless in these locations. There is either a physical switch or a Function key on the keyboard to do this.

Comment: Thanks! I'll try it, next time I'm near that public wifi.

Comment: Sadly, this only works temporarily for me. After connecting to that WIFI _once_, Windows wants to connect to that Network and can only be stopped by forgetting the network. :(

Comment: Did you also clear all auto login forms on all your browsers?  Once you forget the network it should not automatically connect.  Yes it will ask, of course, but it should not be automatic. I clarified my answer in this regard.